# Cannot access array elements outside loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, asynchronous

I have this endpoint in node js and express,  that adds students to an array. I pass the class name and an array of emails in the body of the request. The logic goes as follows:

- Search whether the class exists using the class name passed. If the class exists then iterate through the array of emails, searching whether a user with the email exists and has role member. If they satisfy that, then add them to the array.

The problem:

- When I try to console log the array inside the loop it shows me that the student object was added to the array. However, when outside the loop, I get an empty array on console.log

Here's the actual code I'm trying to describe:

```
const findClass = LessonClass.findOne({className: req.body.className}).exec();
findClass.then(classObject => {
       // check that each emails exists and has role member
       const studentArray = [];
       const emailBody = req.body.email;
       emailBody.forEach(email => User.findOne({email}).exec().then(userObject => {
           if(userObject.role !== 'member'){
               return res.status(400).send({
                   error: 'Only users with role member can be added to a class as students'
               });
           }
           const student = {
               email: userObject.email,
               studentName: userObject.firstName + ' '+ userObject.lastName
           };
           // add the student to the student array
           studentArray.push(student);
           console.log(studentArray); // returns student object inside array
       })
           .catch(err => {
               console.log(err);
           }));
         console.log(studentArray) //returns empty array
   })
```

Anyone help?

Comment: Your code is async and the second `console.log(studentArray)` is called firsts (before your async request done). You can access file array inside `.then`. Or you can try to use `async`

Comment: Thanks @Pvl. Makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your code might be still adding students when you logged them out see this code

```
const findClass = LessonClass.findOne({ className: req.body.className}).exec();
findClass.then(classObject => {
  // check that each emails exists and has role member
  const studentArray = [];
  const emailBody = req.body.email;
  emailBody.forEach(email => User.findOne({email}).exec()
    .then(userObject => {
      if (userObject.role !== 'member') {
        return res.status(400).send({
          error: 'Only users with role member can be added to a class as students'
        });
      }
      const student = {
        email: userObject.email,
        studentName: userObject.firstName + ' ' + userObject.lastName
      };
      // add the student to the student array
      studentArray.push(student);
      console.log(studentArray); // returns student object inside array
      return studentArray;
    })
    .then(students => {
      console.log(students);
    }));
})
```

What I have done is, I removed your `console.log` and chained it with second `then` and from your first `then` returned the students array.

In javascript the callbacks are non blocking, i.e. they won't block the sequence of execution and control will go to next statements. When you declared the `studentsArray` and initiated the non sync operation (promise) it didn't wait for the execution to complete and went straight to `console.log` statement.

Comment: Thanks @Umair Abid. Makes much sense and worked for me